# What condition for $n$ such that $G_n$ is graph planar?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let $G_n$ be the simple graph with the set of vertices $V_n=\{1, 2, . . . , n\}$. Two different vertices $x$ and $y$ are adjacent if $x$ is a multiple of $y$ or $y$ is a multiple of $x$. For what $n$ is $G_n$ planar?

I tried to draw graph starting from small $n$ until I cannot draw graph $G_n$ it without crossings. When that happens, moving some of the vertices so I can avoid the crossings. But I cannot find which $n$ is $G_n$ graph planar?

Any hint is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the requirement for a graph to be non-planar? And how far did you get?

Comment: You've got a sensible idea.  Once you reach where you think the limit is from experimentation, you can see if Kuratowski's theorem proves that the $G_n$ that you can't make is actually non-planar.

Comment: @Arthur: Yes, I do. I tried to find either a subdivision of $K_{3,3}$ or $K_5$ when having crossings.

Answer (score 1):

If $n\geq18$ the graph $G_n$ is not planar since the vertices $\{1,2,3,6,12,18\}$ are the vertices of a $K_{3,3}$ inside $G_n$.

Comment: $K_5$ given by $\{1, 2, 4, 8, 16\}$ is smaller.

Comment: $1,2,4,8,16$ and $1,2,4;8,12,16$ could be considered too

Comment: @Arthur, yes, but I'm not wrong :)